# uniform convergence of series with log

Tags: analysis

Show that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac xn-\log⁡(1+\tfrac xn)\right)$$ 
Converges uniformly on $(-1, A)$ for all $A >-1$ and that the sum of the series has derivatives of all orders on $(-1,\infty)$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please show us what you have tried so far 
and where you are stuck, i.e edit your post with this information
, so that someone can help you. Just stating 
a question like this then it is likely it will get closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : Show that the series is Cauchy-uniform. Once you have written $$\sup_{(-1,A)} \left| \sum_{n=p+1}^q \left(\frac xn-\log⁡(1+\tfrac xn)\right)\right| \leqslant \sum_{n=p+1}^q \sup_{(-1,A)} \left|\frac xn-\log⁡(1+\tfrac xn)\right|,$$ try the overestimate  $\sup_{(-1,A)} \left|\frac xn-\log⁡(1+\tfrac xn)\right|$ by the general term of an absolute convergent series.